# R Maps Geoid to Longitude and Latitude

Tags: r, maps

Good Afternoon,

I'm trying to make my first map in R and could use some help converting the GEOID to a long/lat distance. Here's a sample:

```
geoid               name                                    population
15000US110010001001 Block Group 1, District of Columbia, DC 1405
15000US110010001002 Block Group 2, District of Columbia, DC 1362
15000US110010001003 Block Group 3, District of Columbia, DC 1245
```

Can someone please help? When I try to search for this online, it doesn't help that there seem to be 10 digit geoids and 19 digit ones and even a 12.

Comment: [Here's some information about what you have](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/geoidentifiers.html); basically it's a lot of nested FIPS codes mashed together. There are various packages to munge Census data, some of which may help split it up, e.g. `censusr:::get_geo_url('15000US110010001001', 'bg')`, but really you've got just about as much information in the `name` as the `geoid`. Finding a geocoder that knows anything about block groups may be difficult, though.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90245/census-block-geoid2-conversion-to-latitude-longitude